# exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x0527347c, L:/192.168.3.123:9300 - R:/192.168.3.135:60581]], closing connection java.io.IOException

Tags: elasticsearch

When using ElasticSearch 5.5.1 on Windows10, I always get this warn information. But on Ubuntu, it's ok.

```html
[2017-11-22T22:52:44,667][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [qa_zte] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x0527347c, L:/192.168.3.123:9300 - R:/192.168.3.135:60581]], closing connection
java.io.IOException: 杩滅▼涓绘満寮鸿揩鍏抽棴浜嗕竴涓幇鏈夌殑杩炴帴銆?
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197) ~[?:?]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledHeapByteBuf.setBytes(PooledHeapByteBuf.java:261) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:372) ~[netty-transport-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:123) [netty-transport-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:644) [netty-transport-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:544) [netty-transport-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498) [netty-transport-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:458) [netty-transport-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.11.Final.jar:4.1.11.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_131]
```

Could you give a hand?

Comment: Can't help unless you fix the locale problem to show correct exception info. At least try to interpret the error encoding exception from GB18030 (I guess) to unicode.

Answer (score 0):

please open `elasticsearch.in.bat` then find and set `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` into `GBK`.